# Remove rows which have values before a specific time stamp

Tags: r

Inserting a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), time = c("2020-11-04T13:29:30Z", "2016-10-30T21:10:39Z", "2019-10-30T21:10:39Z"))
```

How is it possible to filter out rows which have time before 2017-01-01

Example of output:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,3), time = c("2020-11-04T13:29:30Z", "2019-10-30T21:10:39Z"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the `time` to `POSIXct` format and use `subset` to keep the rows after  `'2017-01-01'`.

```
df$time <- as.POSIXct(df$time, format = '%Y-%m-%dT%T', tz = 'UTC')
subset(df, time > as.POSIXct('2017-01-01', tz = 'UTC'))
```

Using `dplyr` and `lubridate` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(time = ymd_hms(time)) %>%
  filter(time > ymd('2017-01-01'))

#  id                time
#1  1 2020-11-04 13:29:30
#2  3 2019-10-30 21:10:39
```